# Incremental hierarchical structure of representatives

Tags: algorithm, tree, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have an incremental clustering algorithm following this scheme:

```
Let x a new data-point, and c the centroid that is closest from x
if( distance(x, c) > threshold )
   x becomes a new cluster center (i.e. a new centroid)
else assign x to c (i.e. update the centroid by taking x)
```

In order to speed up the search for the closest center from x, I want to have a hierarchical structuring of centers (using a tree), that we can incrementally update each time a new data-point is considered.

Each internal node of the tree is represented as the average of centroids under that node. When updating a given centroid (because a new data-point was assigned to this centroid), we should rebuild all the nodes that are above this centroid.

Thus the algorithm becomes something like:

```
Let x a new data-point
c = searchClosestCenter(x, tree) // return the centroid closest to x
if( distance(x, c) > threshold )
   x becomes a new cluster center (i.e. a new centroid)
   AddCenterToTree(x, tree)
else
   assign x to c (i.e. update the centroid by taking x)
   UpdateTree(c) // update all nodes that are  on top of c
```

How can this functions be defined in this case ? Is there any better solution to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an **R-tree**? It uses minimum bounding rectangles to summarize the objects in leaf pages. You could also use an kd-tree, but it's performance degrades over time (unless you rebuild it) because it can become unbalanced.

Anyway, R-tree is a really popular data structure for this type of data. It's used in Oracle, SQLite, Postgres, MySQL, ...

R*-trees are an improved version of the R-tree. They have a much better split strategy, slight changes to insertion, and reinserts as an alternative to splitting to improve tree balancing. Search is identical.

As an optimization, you can enhance the R-tree with the following optimization: instead of removing the old entry and inserting the new entry, you can also add a "replace" operation. You first check where the new mean would be inserted. If it is the same page as it was before, just replace it in the page, and eventually update the bounding boxes.

Comment: Ok, but is R-tree incremental (i.e. allow me to add/update/remove leafs without rebuilding the whole hierarchy) ? It is not clear how to use it in my case (see my second algorithm description), I've found an implementation in C++ (which is convenient for me), but it is not straightforward to see what are the functions I need to call, according my algorithm.

Comment: This is the C++ implementation that I found implemented in a single header file RTree.h : http://superliminal.com/sources/RTreeTemplate.zip

Comment: Yes, R-tree is a self-balancing tree, designed for changes.

Comment: Also, is there any disadvantages or gaps in R-tree that one can improve (for what I want to do) ?

Comment: The R*-tree is better than the R-tree, but a bit more complicated to implement. You can probably leave out the reinsertions, if you reinsert the objects anyway. I'll add a note about optimization to the answer in a minute.